# replace dataframe column values with values from an other dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

Let me explain my problem a bit more. I have a dataframe with ID, name and surname, let's call him df_src ex :

```
ID        Name       Surname
177015H   LAURE      Thomas
198786X   ANGEARD    Audrey
136235G   EYSSERIC   Laurent
198786X   ANGEARD    Audrey
```

In this dataframe i have multiple values that are duplicated. Due to the fact that a person can manage diffrent people.
In the other hand my second dataframe contains each of previous rows without the duplicated values + pseudonymize data, let's call him df_tem ex :

```
ID        Name       Surname       FakeID    FakeName       FakeSurname
177015H   LAURE      Thomas        127345H   ELOR           Lori
198786X   ANGEARD    Audrey        112846X   RELARD         Pierre
136235G   EYSSERIC   Laurent       108456G   SERIC          Marc
...       ...        ...           ....      ...            ...
```

What i want to accomplish here is to replace all values from df_src that are similar to the one on df_tem by the fake value. For ex Replace all duplicated values of 177015H LAURE Thomas by 127345H ELOR Lori and so on.

I try to use

```
df_src.replace(to_replace=dfsrc['column'], value=df_tem['column'], inplace=True)
```

just to have none in return.
It's been several hour that i'm on it without being able to find a way of doing it with pandas.

Do you have any idea ? Any hep will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would merge both and then rename the columns:

```
df = df_src.merge(df_tem, on=["ID", "Name", "Surname"], how="left"
    ).drop(columns=["ID", "Name", "Surname"]
    ).rename(columns={"FakeID": "ID", "FakeName": "Name", "FakeSurname": "Surname"})
```

Comment: It seems to works :'( 
I will never have enough words to thanks you. It's been hours i'm on it without any issue !
And it was all that simple, thank you !!!